# How to deactivate encoding of the http parameters in JMeter?

Tags: http, request, jmeter, httprequest

I recorded some HTTP requests with opening a starting page, login etc. I also get the viewstate value from the previous request and use it in the next one. To ensure that the http parameters don't get encoded I removed all encoding checkboxes.

But when I start the run the parameters still get encoded (see second screenshot). Why is this happening? I tried it in JMeter 2.11 and 2.13.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What solved the problem was that I recorded it another two times and the second request worked finally. I can't explain why but I think this is always a good way to solve prblems with requests.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issue, and I came to conclusion that *Encode?* only avoids encoding of parameter values, not parameter names (which is your case as well it seems).
I did not find any good solution that worked with *Parameters* tab. Had to switch to **Body Data** and just format my own request. Basically you just change each param-value pair into `param=value` and add `&` to separate parameters:

```
form-login=form-login&form-login:xi-username:xi-username:login=${username}&...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried that but it had the same result.